# Is there some reverse direct method to convert a dictionary to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I was wondering if there is any reverse method for converting a dictionary to dataframe.
Below is an example of a dataframe which I convert into the required format by using the `stack ()`. `To_dict ()` methods directly. Later after data processing I need to convert a dictionary with the same structure to the dataframe `df`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],
                 [5,6,7,8],
                 [9,10,11,12]],
                 columns= ['a','b','c','d'])
```

|  | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 2 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |

```py
d = df.T.stack().to_dict()
print(d)
{('a', 0): 1,
 ('a', 1): 5,
 ('a', 2): 9,
 ('b', 0): 2,
 ('b', 1): 6,
 ('b', 2): 10,
 ('c', 0): 3,
 ('c', 1): 7,
 ('c', 2): 11,
 ('d', 0): 4,
 ('d', 1): 8,
 ('d', 2): 12}
```

For example I have the following dictionary :

```py
d2={('a', 0): 0, ('a', 1): 1, ('a', 2): 1, ('b', 0): 2, ('b', 1): 3, ('b', 2): 5, ('c', 0): 8, ('c', 1): 13, ('c', 2): 21,
 ('d', 0): 34, ('d', 1): 55, ('d', 2): 89}
```

and the wanted result is:

|  | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 2 | 8 | 34 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 13 | 55 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 21 | 89 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `dict` to a Series and `unstack`:

```
assert df.equals(pd.Series(d).unstack().T)
```